# E2 towards secondary over tertiary and primary beta-carbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

I would like to convert this tertiary bromoalkane to this trisubstituted alkene via E2

[image: Desired outcome]

Theoretically, using a strong base (NaOH) would result in the formation of the Zaistev product (tetrasubstituted) as major, which I do not want.

[image: Zaistev product]

If instead I use a sterically hindered base such as t-BuOK I would get the Hofmann product (disubstituted), which I also do not want.

[image: Hofmann Product]

What would I need to use in order to obtain the 'intermediate' trisubstituted alkene? Would it work if I just used a base that's less sterically hindered than t-BuOK but still blocks formation of Zaistev? Like NaOEt for example?

Thank you

Comment: Your "Zaitsev product" cannot exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bredt%27s_rule

Comment: Also, you should remove the hydrogen when eliminating.

Comment: Your corrected Zaistev product (see orthocresol's and Jan's comments) might not form because it is less stable than expected product (thermodynamically). .